# Usar OpenCV no ubuntu c++

Tags: c++, opencv, visão-computacional

Estou usando Ubuntu com a OpenCV para desenvolver um método de visão computacional, antes utilizava no windows a OpenCV e colocava a seguinte configuração no qtCreator para reconhecer a OpencCV.

```
INCLUDEPATH += "C:\OpenCV-QT\install\include"
LIBS += -L"C:\OpenCV-QT\install\x86\mingw\bin" \
    libopencv_core320 \
    libopencv_highgui320 \
    libopencv_videoio320 \
    libopencv_imgcodecs320 \
    libopencv_imgproc320 \
    libopencv_features2d320 \
    libopencv_calib3d320
```

No Ubuntu eu coloquei tanto no diretorio */home/daniel/* quanto na raiz(/), como faço para colocar o caminho do ubuntu no qt igual esse do windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provavelmente deve ser porque o qt não encontra as bibliotecas neste caminho que informou, quando eu instalei o opencv aqui, esses arquivos estavam em "/usr/local/lib", tente isso:usar este caminho para os .so e /usr/local/include/opencv para os .hpp

Comment: Deu certo, tive que compilar a OpenCV para o Ubuntu, e alterar o caminho.